# Finding relationship between two tables

Tags: oracle, greedy

I have two tables `tbl_customer` and `tbl_policy` and i need to join these two tables. But there is no direct relationship of `Pkey` and `Fkey` between these two tables. In this case i know that `tbl_customer` has a field `int_policy` and in `tbl_policy` and its primary key `int_policy_pk` and these two column can be used to join the table.

But in a generalized way i need to write a function to find this relationship (If i don't know about those fields). Is there any algorithms or other ways to do this?

Comment: In the absence of any defined FK constraints you may be able to guess at relationships implied by column names, depending on your naming  conventions and how consistently they are followed, and then confirm the hypothesis by comparing the data. I doubt there is any general algorithm to automate this, though, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you or do you not know the join columns?

Comment: If it isn't defined in the DB via constraints then there is no definitive way. Data analysis and your human ability to see patterns and connections will be the best tools. Access to the application that creates the source data will also help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the above scenarios is just an example. In my case i will be give only two tables and nothing else i need to commpare these two table and need to find a relation if one exists.

Comment: @BriteSponge yes i agree. And is there any such data analysis algorithms or tools available?

Comment: You're going to need to do some data mining, look for patterns, etc.  I agree with the above comment that there probably isn't an automated tool in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately the tools available will be your, eyes, brain and experience. An understanding of how the application works, what it is  supposed to achieve and the business rules will all help. You are now The Detective.